# Is there a way to make a TextView keep switch between two texts in android?

Tags: android

Assuming I have two texts T1 and T2, I want my TextView to show T1 for 10 seconds and then T2 and after another 10s I want to switch back to T1 and keep the loop going. Is there a way to achieve this without creating a logical loop with a for-loop and a separate thread? TIA :)

Comment: As you have already suggested yourself, I think the only way to achieve what you want is to create a new thread, switching focus between the two TextViews in a loop. Only the main thread has control over Views too so you would have to post the commands back to the main thread using the runOnUIThread method.

Comment: view.getHandler.postDelayed(MyRunnable...., 10000) and Myrunnable repost delayable again and again as long view.isAttached to window ;)

Comment: I see, was looking for a shortcut but looks like it's not to be :)